# What is the behavior of the conversion specifier `p` with `NULL` pointer?

Tags: c, null, printf

I wonder if does:

```
void *ptr = NULL;
printf("%p\n", ptr);
```

Will always gives `(nil)` output?

Does it depend on standard library implementation, or it's a C99 standard specification?

Comment: I think that the standard don't define what is the output of printf for `%p` format. It is up to the implementation.

Comment: I rework this question because answers are wrong. This is a problem for a ~5000 views question.

Comment: @Stargateur: on your way to the necromancer badge?

Comment: @chqrlie No just a user from [C chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/38033005#38033005) who affirm that this is undefined behavior but he don't want answer a old question with high score wrong answer... so he want make a new one. So I just try to improve question to convince him to answer here :p.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On my system it yields `(null)` so I guess it's implementation defined. More generally, everything `%p` prints is implementation-defined:

> 7.21.6.1
>
> The argument shall be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer is
>   converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an
>   implementation-defined manner.

Answer (score 5):

> Will always gives (nil)?

Not at all. On my machine (Mac with `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2`) it prints `0x0`.