# why printf is failing for NULL string?

Tags: c

I ran the following tests on my linux box.

test 1:

```
printf("test %s\n", NULL);
printf("test %s\n", NULL);
```

prints:

```
test (null)
test (null)
```

test 2:

```
printf("%s\n", NULL);
printf("%s\n", NULL);
```

prints

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What is the difference in the above tests? Why is segmentation fault not thrown in test 1 above?

I was not able to understand why in the second test, it is failing to print?

Comment: it's undefined behavior, you aren't guaranteed to see consistent results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the warnings in your compiler. You are not printing what you think you are.

My compiler would be happy to inform you that (in both cases):

```
warning: reading through null pointer (argument 2) [-Wformat]
warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘void *’ [-Wformat]
```

As Red Alert says, ALERT!, what you do is undefined behaviour.

Moreover, make sure to check the linked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589342/printing-null-behavior) for a more detailed answer, which is not far from mine.

Comment: @kadina, I see that you got a -2, while the linked answer I posted, has a +8. I think this happens because, there was already an answer, but you didn't look for that. I will you a +1 for balance, but make sure you search better next time. :)