# basic printf behavior with NULL pointer

Tags: c

I found something rather odd with printf.

When I do the following

```
printf ("%s\n", (char *)NULL);
```

I get a segfault.

But when I do this:

```
printf (".%s\n", (char *)NULL);
```

the output is below and no crash.

```
.(null)
```

Does anyone know why the behavior difference?

Comment: Undefined behavior can include *anything*, including this.

Comment: [See this answer (to the question I think this is a duplicate of) for a decently simple explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11589443/1287251). Short answer: `printf("%s\n", ...)` is converted to `puts`, which segfaults on `NULL`, but `printf(".%s\n", ...)` uses the actual `printf` function which converts `NULL` to `(null)`.

Comment: Stop doing odd/bad things and odd/bad things will stop happening.

Comment: You might find something completely different happens on a different target/compiler. As @EOF said, undefined behaviour is just that - learn never to be surprised  by what it actually ends up doing

Comment: What OS and compiler?

Comment: @Olaf: Incorrect. If you want to pass a null pointer to `printf`, you *need* to cast it to the appropriate pointer type. Without the cast, if `NULL` is defined as `0`, you're passing an `int`, not a `char*`. That doesn't really apply in this case, since the behavior is undefined anyway, but it does apply to `printf("%p\n", (void*)NULL)`. But passing a pointer to a variadic function is (I think) the only case where you really need to cast `NULL` to a pointer type.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Heck, I always forget about varargs. Thanks. Btw. things are even worse, as a null pointer might have different representation, depending on the target type.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the generated assembly code, you will see that `printf ("%s\n",…)` has been [optimized by the compiler](https://goo.gl/Ep2gga) into a call to `puts`, whereas other format strings do not lend themselves to this trick.

It so happens that on your platform, the `printf` function detects null pointers and kindly avoids to crash, whereas the `puts` function doesn't.

The distinction doesn't matter: it is undefined behavior to pass a null pointer to `printf` for `%s`. Do no do it ever, even if, on your particular compilation platform, you were lucky the second time.

Comment: This answer is a copy from the duplicate answer. Better close as duplicate then answer this.

Comment: @SergeyA I'm going to assume that English is not your native language and that you are not really accusing me of plagiarism just because my answer states the same information that already exists elsewhere.

Comment: I didn't mean to accuse you of anything, I just mentioned that it is a duplication of the same detail. SO promotes closig duplicates as such, rather than answering them.

Comment: @SergeyA In this case, I am sorry to tell you that “This answer is a copy from the duplicate answer” does not mean what you wanted to say, and the question is now closed.

Comment: Yes, I should probably have said 'copy of' rather than 'copy from'. My apologies for improper use of wording.

Comment: @SergeyA That's like arguing that “Wikipedia is a copy of the Encyclopedia Britannica” is more correct than “Wikipedia is a copy from the Encyclopedia Britannica”.