# Why can GCC assume VTables end up at 32-bit adresses

Tags: gcc

Consider the following program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public:
        A() {}
        virtual void a() {};
};

class B : public A { };

int main() {
    B();
}
```

GCC (tested 4.4.0, 8.3.0 and 9.1) generates the following Code for `B::B()` ([godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/l7tAGE)):

```
        call    A::A() [base object constructor]
        movl    $vtable for B+16, %edx
```

Note that it does a 32-bit move in a 64-bit program. How can GCC be sure that the `.text` section storing the vtable will end up in a 32-bit address?

Comment: Because GCC knows where everything is, as it is itself responsible for placing the data there?

Comment: Well, I assume that it can provide the linker with the right flags to arrange it in a way that that is the case. I was wondering where that is appearant in assembler output, which it doesn't seem to be. E.g. you have to provide the right linker flags when linking the resulting a.out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by GCC's small code model ([`-mcmodel=small`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.3/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html)). Try adding `-mcmodel=large` to the compiler options and see how it will emit a `movabsq` instead.

Cudos to [How can gcc/clang assume a string constant's address is 32-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183515/how-can-gcc-clang-assume-a-string-constants-address-is-32-bit).