# Partially filled array in c gives segmentation fault while printing in C

Tags: c, arrays

I get a segmentation fault when I run the following program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()

{

    char *a[10] = {"hi", "hello", "how"};
    int i ;
    printf("%s %s %s %s %s\n",a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]);
    for (i = 0;i < 10; i++)
        printf("%s\n",a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
hi hello how (null) (null)

hi

hello

how

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)  and Linux kernel 3.16.0-34-generic.

I know that all the non initialized array entries get the value 0, so I expect a `null` at the printf.
But it gives segmentation fault.

Strangely when I replaced the `printf (“%s\n”,a[i])`  with p`rintf(“%s  %d\n”,a[i],i)` I am able to get `null` for the unfilled array entry.

In fact a space between `%s` and `\n` too is free from segmentation fault.

Can anybody tell me the reason behind this behavior.

Comment: just to clarify, the segmentation fault only occurs after that `for` loop correct? If you were to remove the for loop you get no error?

Comment: That's funny. I have copied your program exactly and it does not give me a segmentation fault.

Comment: `null` is not the nul character `'\0'`, thus printf will not recognize it as a (zero-length) string, and you get undefined behaviour. It may print `(null)`, it may crash, it may blow up your computer.

Comment: Don't try to make sense of undefined behavior. It's pointless.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589342/what-is-the-behavior-of-printing-null-with-printfs-s-specifier

Comment: @iRove weird. When I try her code on my C++ (I don't have a plain C compiler) compiler it also throws now errors. I'm on windows using Visual Studio's compiler.

Comment: This is an undefined behavior. Non initialized array could contain any value, this is implementation and even configuration specific.

Comment: @AshwinGupta: See [Evert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/707650/evert)'s comment above.  The undefined behavior might very well change depending on your system.  The Earth could explode, _literally anything_ could happen ([see here for more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/4520911))

Comment: @iRove yeah thats very interesting. I never knew about this. Learned something new today!

Comment: @Ari0nhh It's undefined because `NULL` is passed to `printf()` for the `%s` specifier, but not because the array could contain unknown values... the array *is* initialized (the unspecified values will be `NULL`).

Comment: Reason is puts calling strlen to know the length of the string. Your printf will be replaced by puts by the compiler.
If you pass a NULL string to strlen, the program crashes for NULL pointer dereference (with signal SIGSEGV). Check with gdb you can see SIGSEGV by strlen.

Answer (score 3):

depending on your compiler, your second `printf` will be replaced by a `puts`

see the [assembly result](https://godbolt.org/g/MWqiYW)
and it seems that your system implementation of `puts` will crash with `NULL` as a parameter.

Comment: In addition to this, `printf("%s", NULL);` is undefined behaviour, so the fact that it ever worked is more by coincidental generosity than expectation. That kind of code shouldn't be relied upon...

Comment: You are certainly pointing the gist of the problem here, I was merely pointing why the two calls could behaved differently.

Comment: Indeed. Your answer explained a good example where the generosity is stripped away in favour of optimisations (also coincidental).