# strtok seems to delete string portion - Am I using it right?

Tags: c, string, pointers, strtok

I want to use strtok() to divide a line into tokens, but the function seems to just make the first token and "destroying" the rest. I used printf() to check where did that happen and found out it was just after `token= strtok(line,delimit)`. 
Here's my main, read_line and parse_args functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define PROMPT "$"
#define MAX_LINE 512
void main(){
    char line[MAX_LINE]; 
    while(read_line(line)){
        execute_line(line);
    }
}

char *read_line(char *line){ 
    printf("%s ",PROMPT);
    fflush(stdout);
    line=fgets(line,MAX_LINE,stdin);
    return line;
}

int parse_args(char **args, char *line){
    printf("%s", line); //If it reads "Hello how are you?", here it prints properly
    int n=0;
    char* token;
    char delimit[]=" \t\r\n\v\f";
    token=strtok(line,delimit);
    printf("%s", line); //however here it just prints "Hello" 
    while(token!=NULL){
        printf("token%i: %s\n",n,token);
        *args=token;
        n++;
        *args++;
        token=strtok(NULL,delimit);
    }
    printf("token%i: %s\n",n,token);
    *args=token;
    return n;
}

int execute_line(char *line){
    char **args;
    parse_args(args,line);
    check_internal(args);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void main` is wrong; `main` should return `int`.

Comment: You're missing several `#include`s.

Comment: `MAX_LINE` is not defined.

Comment: See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok. Specifically the 6th bullet for #1.

Comment: You never call `parse_args`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtok` replaces delimiters with NUL characters so that it can return pointers to the tokens still in the original buffer.

The `*args++` is misleading.  It does increment `args`, but the `*` is unnecessary.

Comment: Ohh yes.  The `*` is unnecessary.

Comment: @KeineLust *`parse_args()` is never called in the OPs code.*  Most likely, the OP just failed to post a full MCVE.

Comment: thanks @pat , it was that *, however now it reports a segmentation fault...

Comment: Now that I can see `execute_line`, I can see that you aren't allocating any memory for the `args` array.  You should declare `args` as `char *args[MAX_ARGS+1]` in `execute_line` (and pick some value for `MAX_ARGS`; the `+1` is for the `NULL` you are storing at the end).  Be aware that, with the current code, if there are too many args, it will overflow the array; you should perform a bounds check.

Comment: Oh, and declaring `delimit` as an array will cause the function to copy the string onto the stack every time you call `parse_args`.  It's better to declare `delimit` as `const char *delimit = "..."` so you can use the copy in the constant strings section.

Comment: Also, when you drop out of the `while` loop, `token` will necessarily be `NULL` (that was the bound on the loop), so it's probably not a good idea to pass `NULL` to `printf` with a `%s` format char (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589342/what-is-the-behavior-of-printing-null-with-printfs-s-specifier)).

Answer (score 0):

Per [the standard declaration](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html):

```
#include <string.h>

char *strtok(char *restrict s, const char *restrict sep);
```

Note *well* that `char *restrict s` contains no `const`.  `strtok()` modifies the string it's splitting into tokens.

Answer (score -1):

```
token=strtok(line,delimit);
printf("%s", line); //however here it just prints "Hello"
```

that's exactly what strtok does :)

It actually takes your line, and puts a '\0' instead of the next delimiter.
You should try looking at your code with a debugger, it will make more sense to use strtok after that.

Good luck!