# Segmentation fault (core dumped) c

Tags: c

Here is a weird problem:

```
token = strtok(NULL, s);
printf(" %s\n", token);  // these two lines can read the token and print
```

However!

```
token = strtok(NULL, s);
printf("%s\n", token); // these two lines give me a segmentation fault
```

Idk whats happened, because I just add a space before  %s\n, and I can see the value of token.

my code:

```
int main() {    

    FILE *bi;

    struct _record buffer;

    const char s[2] = ",";
    char str[1000];
    const char *token;

    bi = fopen(DATABASENAME, "wb+");


    /*get strings from input, and devides it into seperate struct*/
    while(fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin)!= NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", str); // can print string line by line
            token = strtok(str, s);
            strcpy(buffer.id, token);
            printf("%s\n", buffer.id); //can print the value in the struct
            while(token != NULL){
                token = strtok(NULL, s);
                printf("%s\n", token); // problem starts here
                /*strcpy(buffer.lname, token);  
                printf("%s\n", buffer.lname); // cant do anything with token */        
    }}

    fclose(bi);

    return 1;}
```

Here is the example of string I read from stdin and after parsed(I just tried to strtok the first two elements to see if it works):

<15322101,MOZNETT,JOSE,n/a,n/a,2/23/1943,MALE,824-75-8088,42 SMITH AVENUE,n/a,11706,n/a,n/a,BAYSHORE,NY,518-215-5848,n/a,n/a,n/a
<
< 15322101
<  MOZNETT

Comment: Do you know how to use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)?

Comment: it would be helpful if you share an example of the string being parsed so we can reproduce it, please add it to the question.

Comment: Make sure `token` isn't `NULL`

Comment: I can run my function well in my terminal, but my instructor requires me to submit it to Vocareum, and these function isn't work on that website. It seems no debug option on Vocareum.

Comment: @jiaru zhu  You need to check whether token is equal to NULL. Also it is  unclear how buffer.id is declared.

Comment: Never use `strtok`, use `strtok_r` instead.

Comment: problem seems to be when token is NULL, I can reproduce that on my machine. `printf("%s\n",NULL)` gives segmentation fault, while `printf(" %s\n",NULL)`  prints  (null).

Comment: @AndrésAlcarraz: That's because some compilers, gcc for example, transform `printf("%s\n", s)` to the simpler and more direct  `puts(s);` and `printf` catches null strings, but `puts` doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem reduces to the following question [What is the behavior of printing NULL with printf's %s specifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589342/what-is-the-behavior-of-printing-null-with-printfs-s-specifier)
.

In short NULL as an argument to a `printf("%s")` is undefined. So you need to check for NULL as suggested by @kninnug

You need to change you printf as follows:

```
token = strtok(NULL, s);
if (token != NULL) printf("%s\n", token);
```

Or else

```
printf ("%s\n", token == NULL ? "" : token);
```

Comment: I fixed my code like this:  if(token== NULL){
                                              print("%s\n", "1")}
                                 else{
                                             token = strtok(NULL, s);
                                       strcpy(buffer.lname, token);
                      printf("%s\n", buffer.lname);}    //still not working

Comment: Check after strtok.

Comment: I added an if conditon like  if(token!= NULL)  after both strtok method,  but still segmentation fault. :(

Comment: @jiaruzhu  I changed the answer expliciting where the check would be

Answer (score 2):

In the first version your compiler transforms `printf()` into a
`puts()` and puts does not allow null pointers, because internally
invokes the `strlen()` to determine the lenght of the string.

In the case of the second version you add a space in front of format
specifier. This makes it impossible for the compiler to call puts
without appending this two string together. So it invokes the actual
printf() function, which can handle `NULL` pointers. And your code
works.