# Different output when printing a null char pointer with and without a newline appended

Tags: c, pointers

I tried the following code on Linux

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *p=NULL;
    printf("%s",p);
    return 0;
}

#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *p=NULL;
    printf("%s\n",p);
    return 0;
}
```

The first one outputs:   `(null)`

While the second one causes a segmentation fault.

Why does `\n` make such a difference?

Comment: Hmm, I would have expected a `(null)` as well, but I also get the segfault. Replacing `\n` with something else, like `printf("%su", p)` prints `(null)u`. Even adding a space before `\n` prints `"(null) "`. Now I'm curious.

Comment: Both are undefined behavior

Comment: @Pablo It doesn't matter what result you get. The code is UB and may give any result.

Comment: @Pablo Flag as duplicate with that link if you think it's more appropriate.

Comment: @4386427 I didn't that this was UB, using gcc I've always seen `(null)` being printed when passing `NULL` to `%s`, so I assumed that this was normal behaviour. Now I know better.

Comment: @Pablo Calling `printf(%s....", ptr);` with `ptr` being NULL is UB per standard

Comment: It is a duplicate to Pablo's link, but not to Jacob's.

Comment: @4386427 yes, I said that I didn't know that, hence my confusion. Now I know thanks to you and the link I found.

Comment: @Pablo Thanks to your link ,it  solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your examples are undefined behavior per standard. Calling `printf` with `%s` and passing a NULL pointer is UB.

Therefore it makes no sense to discuss the outcome. On one system you might get one result and on another system you get another result.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11589479/4386427