# Dynamically expanding C code without using realloc

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I need to put the names separated by commas from the text into struct that expands dynamically, but I am prohibited from using realloc ().I'm getting a core dumped error in this code. What is the error in this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct movie{

    double budget;
    int genre;
    char* name;
    double score;
    int year;
};


void recorder_function(struct movie *movies){

    FILE*fp;
    fp=fopen("Movies.txt","r");
    struct movie *p;
    int i,n=0;
    char line[1000];
    char temp_budget[50];
    char temp_name[50];
    char temp_genre[50];
    
    while (!feof(fp)) {
    
        fgets(line,1000,fp);
        sscanf(line,"%50[^,],%50[^,],%50[^,]",temp_budget,temp_genre,temp_name);
        
//I open the fields in this section

        movies=(struct movie *)calloc(n+1,sizeof(struct movie));
        p=(struct movie *)calloc(n+1,sizeof(struct movie));
        
        p[n].name=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(temp_name)+1));
        movies[n].name=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(temp_name)+1));

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        movies[i]=p[i];

        strcpy(movies[n].name,temp_name);

        free(p);
            
        p=movies;

        n++;
        
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%s\n",movies[i].name);
        

}

int main(){

    int choice;
    struct movie *movies;
    recorder_function(movies);
}
```

Comment: Rousso, Who or what text suggested using `while (!feof(fp)) {`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: With scanf, the field width should be at most 1 less than the size of the buffer.  So `char temp_budget[50];` goes with `sscanf("%49[^,]", ...)`

Comment: If you're not allowed to use `realloc()`, you have to read the file twice. First to get the number lines so you can allocate the `movies` array the proper size. Then the second time to fill it in.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I got it, but I gave the word size too much, normal 10 does not exceed 15 words The words in the txt

Comment: Why does `recorder_function()` take `movies` as a parameter? It immediately overwrites it with `calloc()`.

Comment: I see, you're trying to implement your own `realloc()` by calling `calloc()` and then copying from the previous one.

Comment: yes but i get a core dumped error

Comment: You should check if `fopen()` succeeded.

Comment: when i print it sequentially i see that there is no problem reading the file but the last time i print i see that it was not saved to the movies struct and it gave an error

Comment: It is not guaranteed what happens when `NULL` is passed for `%s` format specifier. [c - What is the behavior of printing NULL with printf's %s specifier? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589342/what-is-the-behavior-of-printing-null-with-printfs-s-specifier)

Comment: Why does it allocate memory for both `movies` and `p` in the loop?

Comment: p[n].name should also be freed? might  be memory leak

Comment: BTW: this is not related to your problem, but the casts before `malloc` and friends are useless. `= (char*)malloc(...` -> `= malloc(...` etc.

Comment: To keep data while growing dynamically because I am prohibited from using realloc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bad idea to overwrite the pointer `movie` by newly allocated clean buffer.

Instead of that, you should

1. Allocate new buffer only for `p`.
2. Put the new element to `p[n]`
3. Put existing elements `movie[0], ... , movie[n-1]` to `p[0], ... , p[n-1]`
4. Free the old buffer `movie`
5. Assign the new buffer `p` to `movie`

Don't forget to initialize `movie` not to cause troubles at the first freeing.

Also `while (!feof(fp))` is [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) and you should check if readings are successful after trying to read and before using what are read.

One more important point is that you should make sure that `fopen()` succeeded. Passing `NULL`, which `fopen()` returns on failure`, to other file manipulation functions may cause troubles.

Another point is that your arrays used for `sscanf()` outputs should have one more elements for the terminating null-character.

Yet another point is that casting results of `malloc()` family is [considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Try this:

```
void recorder_function(struct movie *movies){

    FILE*fp;
    fp=fopen("Movies.txt","r");
    if(fp==NULL){
        fputs("file open error\n", stderr);
        return;
    }
    struct movie *p;
    int i,n=0;
    char line[1000];
    char temp_budget[51];
    char temp_name[51];
    char temp_genre[51];
    
    movies=NULL;
    
    while (fgets(line,1000,fp)) {
    
        sscanf(line,"%50[^,],%50[^,],%50[^,]",temp_budget,temp_genre,temp_name);
        
//I open the fields in this section

        p=calloc(n+1,sizeof(struct movie));
        
        p[n].name=malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(temp_name)+1));
        strcpy(p[n].name,temp_name);

        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            p[i]=movies[i];
        }

        free(movies);

        movies=p;

        n++;
        
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%s\n",movies[i].name);
    }

}
```

The next stage will be fixing the weird usage of the argument `movie`. Arguments in C are *copies* of what are passed, and modifications of arguments in callee functions won't affect what are passed in caller. Your choice is:

- Remove the argument `movies` and convert that to a local variable.
- Have `recorder_function` take a pointer to `struct movie*` (`struct movie**`) and have it use the pointer to modify what caller specifies. (You also have to change the statement to call the function to pass a pointer in this case)

Comment: @Rousso If you are prohibited from using `realloc()` for academic purposes then this solution is fine.  If it is prohibited for some technical reason, then be aware that this solution is _exactly_ how `realloc()` works and may therefore be prohibited too.