# printf returns 6 instead of 0 when assigning a null string

Tags: c, printf, null-string

Why does `printf` function return 6 instead of 0 when assigning `NULL` as string to it, although its printing nothing?

```
int main(void)
{
    int x;
    x = printf("%s", NULL);
    printf ("\n%d", x);
}
```

output is:

```
(null)
6
```

Comment: Doesn't it print `(null)`? that's 6 chars.

Comment: is (null) counted as string?

Comment: @DeeA it returns the number of characters outputted. so it is 6

Comment: @DeeA Maybe you meant to use `""` (empty string) instead of `NULL` (invalid pointer)?

Comment: Check the "return value" section in the [printf manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)

Comment: Totally unrelated, but please make it a habit to use *trailing* newlines in your output. Some shells wont handle output not ending in a newline that well (so the output and the shell prompt is on the same line). And output to a terminal is usually line-buffered, so a leading newline writes the *previous* output, not the current one.

Comment: [What is the behavior of printing NULL with printf's %s specifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589342/what-is-the-behavior-of-printing-null-with-printfs-s-specifier)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why does printf function return 6 instead of 0 when assigning NULL as string to it

Because it printed 6 chars. "(null)" is 6 chars.

> although its printing nothing?

It is printing "(null)". That's 6 chars.

Note that passing `NULL` as an argument to `%s` format specifier is *invalid* in the first place and causes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior). Some implementations, like the one you are using, are printing "(null)" instead of crashing.

Comment: Answer uses `NULL`  (using code format) as a descriptor of the code and the later uses `(null)`  (also using code format)  to indicate a select text output.  Consider "(null)" instead to add clarity.