# Why do I an get error when trying to print a null pointer

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main ()
{
    int* p = NULL;
    printf("%d", *p);
}
```

It prints:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
p was nullptr.
```

Comment: You're not printing the null pointer, you're printing to where it points to. Which you can't do with a null pointer. Try printing `p` instead of `*p`. Also, print pointers using `%p`, not `%d`.

Comment: OT: It has to be `int main()` at least, or even better `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour of `int* p = NULL; *p;` is *undefined*.

If you want to print out the *address* of `p`, then use `"%p"` as the format specifier, and drop the dereference:

```
printf("%p", (void*)p);
```

The cast to `(void*)` is required in order to match exactly the format specifier.

Answer (score 7):

NULL pointers may not be dereferenced.

Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case manifested in your program crashing.

This is documented in section 6.5.3.2p4 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *4* The unary
>   `*` operator denotes indirection.  If the operand points to a function, the result is a  function  designator;  if  it  points  to  an 
>   object,  the  result  is  an  lvalue  designating  the object.   If 
>   the  operand  has  type  "pointer  to type",  the  result  has 
>   type  "type".   **If  an invalid  value  has  been  assigned  to 
>   the  pointer,  the  behavior  of  the  unary
>   * operator  is undefined. <sup>102)</sup>**
>
> *102)* Thus, `&*E` is equivalent to `E` (even if E is a null pointer), and
>   `&(E1[E2])` to `((E1)+(E2))`.  It is always  true  that  if `E` is  a 
>   function  designator  or  an  lvalue  that  is  a  valid  operand  of 
>   the  unary `&` operator,
>   `*&E` is a function designator or an lvalue equal to `E`. If
>   `*P` is an lvalue and `T` is the name of an object pointer type,
>   `*(T)P` is an lvalue that has a type compatible with that to which `T` points.
>
> **Among  the  invalid  values  for  dereferencing  a  pointer 
>   by  the  unary
>   `*` operator  are  a  null  pointer**, an address inappropriately aligned for the type of object pointed to, and the address of an object after
>   the end of its lifetime.

If you want to print the pointer itself, pass it to `printf` without dereferencing it and use the `%p` format specifier:

```
printf("%p\n", (void *)p);
```

Comment: Related, FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44996471/printing-null-pointers-with-p-is-undefined-behavior

Comment: For completeness: Also to this "*NULL pointers may not be dereferenced*" important rule the usual exception exist. An "invalid" pointer may be dereferenced when the `sizeof` operator is applied to it. For example doing `size_t size_of_int = sizeof *((int*) NULL);` is valid.